# Docker compose error sed: can't create temp file: Permission denied

Tags: docker, sed, docker-compose

I have a simple Dockerfile as below:-

```
FROM tinkerpop/gremlin-server:3.4.12
```

In my **docker-compose** file I am creating a volume from the config on my host machine in **./test/db/conf** which contains the **gremlin-server.yaml** file as below

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  gremlin-server:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./test/db/conf:/opt/gremlin-server/conf_local
    ports:
      - 8182:8182
    command: ./conf_local/gremlin-server.yaml
```

This works fine on Mac, but on WSL on Windows, and on Ubuntu, I get a permission error from sed when running the command

```
docker compose up --build
```

The error is

```
gremlin-server_1  | sed: can't create temp file './conf_local/gremlin-server.yamlXXXXXX': Permission denied
```

I understand this is related to permissions on the host but I'm at a loss as to how to resolve it and would appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the actual `sed` command you're running?  In the Compose file you set `command:` to a YAML file; is that executable, does the Dockerfile have an `ENTRYPOINT` you haven't shown, something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need a permission to add files to the directory. Try this  `chmod a+wx ./test/db/conf`

Comment: Thanks Kesha - yep if I broaden the permissions on the host, then it will work, but I don't believe those permissions would survive in source control, so the next person to checkout the code would not inherit the permissions. I don't know if thats the case - I will try, but I was hoping for a solution that did not involve permissions on the host. I can also see why the container should not be able to change permissions of files on the host - but wondering if there is a better solution.

Comment: The solution is adjusting permissions on the host or in the container with a privileged user. Try to commit your directory with permissions and check out to test if they remain.